# SQL Server Management Studio - change connection to registered server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, connection, ssms

Seems like this would be a fairly popular question to get asked, I did a quick search and didn't see anything. I'm curious to see if there is a way around this.

I spend my entire day in SSMS, and I am constantly changing my connection between many different servers while working within the same query file. I have them all set up as Registered servers, but for some reason, the change connection dialog box doesn't link up with that list...This occasionally becomes annoying.

You would think the "Browse for more" option under server name would have a tab for registered servers. I just installed SSMS 2014 today and was hoping maybe there'd be a new feature to cover this or something.

Comment: same problem. its so annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried SSMSBoost?
[SSMSBoost URL](http://www.ssmsboost.com/VersionCompare)

Several of the features include:

- Preferred connections
- Connection aliases/coloring
- Quick Connections Switch
- Drop-down on toolbar, allowing to switch connections between servers